# How can I avoid format changing at <download-excel> in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, ag-grid

I have a AgGrid. There is values and columns. We have a button for download the table as an excel file.

We use this for that:

```
<download-excel class="tool" :data="data.selectedXs" :fields="excelFields">
```

Our excelFileds something like that:

```
excelFieldTr: {
                'keyA': 'fieldA',
                'keyB': 'fieldB'
            },
```

There is values like 51806055792802, 51806055792803 etc. And they are string values.
After I download the excel file I see scientific correspondings for these like 5.18081E+13.

How can I avoid this format change?

Comment: Which excel downloader package u were using ?